# Can't send a message from xmpp4r?

Tags: ruby, xmpp, messaging, xmpp4r

I'm trying to test sending a message to one jid account by using xmpp4r:

```
require 'xmpp4r'
include Jabber

jid = JID::new('alice@wonderland.lit')
password = 'secr3t'

cl = Client::new(jid)
cl.connect('166.78.7.179')
cl.auth(password)
cl.send(Presence.new)

to = 'arthur@wonderland.lit'
subject = 'XMPP4R test'
body = 'Hi, this is a XMPP4R test'
m = Message::new( to, body ).set_type(:chat).set_id('1').set_subject(subject)
cl.send m
```

But I always get the following exception:

```
/home/subout/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@subout/gems/xmpp4r-0.5/lib/xmpp4r/client.rb:118:in `rescue in auth': closed stream (Jabber::ClientAuthenticationFailure)
   from /home/subout/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@subout/gems/xmpp4r-0.5/lib/xmpp4r/client.rb:108:in `auth'
   from send_message2.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

- First of all, would you please add `Jabber::debug = true` setting
  before `cl.connect` and post output here?
- Secondly, it looks like there is a problem with XMPP server (are you sure it’s running at
  '166.78.7.179'?)
- And, the last but not the least, why do you decide
  to use “obsolete” `xmpp4r` rather than it’s modern successor
  [`Blather`](https://github.com/adhearsion/blather)?

Comment: After I switch from Vines to ejabberd, it works fine. I would like to try Blather as well, but how can I send a simple message without blocking with EventMachine?

Comment: Vines has some issues, yeah. Vines Agent code is full of examples of sending non-blocking stanzas w/EM.

Comment: @mudasobwa Looking at vines agent code now but if you could point out such an example I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @gduq An example of what? The simple 6-line echo-bot example is provided at official [Blather page](https://github.com/adhearsion/blather) (scroll to “Examples”.)

Comment: @mudasobwa I'm trying to get Blather going on Windows but there is a 5 years old issue with EM which prevents it from establishing a encrypted connection. xmpp4r has almost no documentation nor examples. The ones I found are wrong or outdated and don't run anymore on current versions. Any advice what else to try?

Comment: @SteffenRoller Unfortunately, no. Sorry for that.